# httpservice...doesn't work on localhost

Tags: apache-flex

I am making a very simple httpservice request w/ a php file that is on my remote server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
           xmlns:halo="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo"
           >

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        private function check(evt:ResultEvent):void
        {
            if(service.lastResult.output == "yes")

            {
                test.text = "successful";
            } 

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>


<fx:Declarations>

<mx:HTTPService id="service" result="check(event)" showBusyCursor="true" method="POST" url="http://www.example.com/php.php" useProxy="false">
</mx:HTTPService>

</fx:Declarations>


<mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%">

<mx:Button x="10" y="122" label="Submit" id="Submit" click="service.send();"/>
<mx:TextArea id="test" width="50%" height="50%" />

</mx:VBox>

</s:Application>
```

When I run the resultant flash file on my remote server, it works 100% and test.text gets populated to "successful".

However, when I run it on localhost test.text is still blank. If I check my network monitor in Flex, the httpservice was successful, so crossdomain.xml seems to be set right ...what am I doing wrong? I've been spinning my wheels for some time w/out a clue. thx!

Comment: Did you debug it on localhost? Does the HTTPService execute your check() function? Otherwise try adding a fault handler to your HTTPService in order to see the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be disallowed by your server's crossdomain.xml file, or maybe you don't have one.

When Flash player looks for some remote stuff served from a different domain than the SWF itself, it checks for a file at the domain root called crossdomain.xml to make sure the server is okay with that.

You might want to put something like this in there that just allows everything, until you're done with your local development...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM
"http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">

<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="SOAPAction"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```